# SQL Query Get Max Value At Occured Date

Tags: mysql, sql, max

So we are doing some traffic reporting in our department.
Therefore we got a table named traffic_report, which is build up like

```
╔════════════════╦═══════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╗
║    hostname    ║ interface ║      date_gmt       ║ intraf_mpbs ║ outraf_mbps ║
╠════════════════╬═══════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ my-machine.com ║ NIC-5     ║ 2013-09-18 09:55:00 ║          32 ║          22 ║
║ my-machine.com ║ NIC-5     ║ 2013-09-17 08:25:00 ║          55 ║          72 ║
║ my-machine.com ║ NIC-5     ║ 2013-09-16 05:12:00 ║          65 ║           2 ║
║ my-machine.com ║ NIC-5     ║ 2013-09-15 04:46:00 ║          43 ║           5 ║
║ my-machine.com ║ NIC-5     ║ 2013-09-14 12:02:00 ║          22 ║          21 ║
║ my-machine.com ║ NIC-5     ║ 2013-09-13 22:13:00 ║          66 ║          64 ║
╚════════════════╩═══════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╝
```

I'd like to fetch the maximum of the traffic in and traffic out at the occured date.
My approach doing so is like this

```
SELECT hostname, interface, date_gmt, max(intraf_mbps) as max_in, max(outtraf_mbps) as max_out
FROM traffic_report
GROUP by hostname, interface
```

The approach produces a table like this

```
╔════════════════╦════════════╦═════════════════════╦════════╦═════════╗
║    hostname    ║ interface  ║      date_gmt       ║ max_in ║ max_out ║
╠════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════════════╬════════╬═════════╣
║ my-machine.com ║ NIC-5      ║ 2013-09-18 09:55:00 ║     66 ║      72 ║
╚════════════════╩════════════╩═════════════════════╩════════╩═════════╝
```

The problem is, the date_gmt displayed is just the date of the first record entered to the table.

How do I instruct SQL to display me the date_gmt at which the max(intraf_mbps) occured?

Comment: what if max_in is on another day as max_out

Comment: that will be most likely true. It would be enough at this point to get one of the correct timestamps

Comment: There is not a unique 'max data', perhaps they are several dates with same max traffic. You can get max traffic in a correlated subquery and filter for records with this traffic. It is a dirty solution, but mysql don't support analytic functions either ranks.

Comment: that would be a feasible approach for now, how do i build up a subquery like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is with [mysql hidden fields](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html):

> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to
>   nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. This means
>   that the preceding query is legal in MySQL. You can use this feature
>   to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and
>   grouping. However, **this is useful primarily when all values in each
>   nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each
>   group.**

Mysql has not rank features either analytic functions, to get your results, a **readable approach but with very poor** performance is:

```
SELECT hostname, 
       interface, 
       date_gmt, 
       intraf_mbps, 
       outtraf_mbps
FROM traffic_report T
where intraf_mbps + outtraf_mbps =
      ( select 
           max(intraf_mbps + outtraf_mbps) 
        FROM traffic_report T2
        WHERE T2.hostname = T.hostname and
              T2.interface = T.interface 
        GROUP by hostname, interface
      )
```

Sure you can work for a solution with more index friendly approach or avoid correlated subquery.

Notice than I have added both rates, in and out. Adapt solution to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Either of these approaches should work:

This first query returns the rows that match the maximum out and in values, so multiple rows can be returned if many records share the max or min values.

```
SELECT * from traffic_report 
WHERE intraf_mpbs = (SELECT MAX(intraf_mpbs) FROM traffic_report) 
   or outraf_mpbs = (SELECT MAX(outraf_mpbs) FROM traffic_report)
```

This second query returns more of a MI style result, add other fields if you require them.

```
SELECT "MAX IN TRAFFIC" AS stat_label,date_gmt AS stat_date, traffic_report.intraf_mpbs
  FROM traffic_report,(select MAX(intraf_mpbs) AS max_traf FROM traffic_report) as max_in
 WHERE traffic_report.intraf_mpbs = max_in.max_traf
 UNION
SELECT "MAX OUT TRAFFIC" AS stat_label,date_gmt AS stat_date, traffic_report.outraf_mpbs
  FROM traffic_report,(SELECT MAX(outraf_mpbs) AS max_traf FROM traffic_report) AS max_out
 WHERE traffic_report.outraf_mpbs = max_out.max_traf
```

Hope this helps.